# Cannot apply prettyUrl to new generate Yii2 project

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii2

Going through a Yii tutorial, I hit a problem right at the start. I am trying to apply prettyURL to a basic yii2 project.

This is the web.php file under /web:

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'hCfpup7Utu5ddLMZQoJ6khEkQiwWlp1j',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];
}

return $config;
```

And this is the .htacces file that i have created in the /web folder (where index.php is):

```
RewriteEngine on


    # If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php
```

Yet the result looks like this:

[image: http://snag.gy/gpXz4.jpg]

If I try to go to another page:

[image: http://snag.gy/uub3o.jpg]

I have already went into XAMPP's httpd.conf and changed all AllowOverides to ALL and verified that

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

is uncommented.

Comment: Try adding `'enableStrictParsing' => false,` to your `'urlManager'` config.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately it did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have following config:

```
'urlManager' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
                    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                    'showScriptName' => false,
                    'rules' => [
                        '' => 'site/index',
                        'login' => 'site/login',
                    ],
                ],
```

and `.htacess` file

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and it runs fine for me.

**EDIT**

You mentioned

> This is the web.php file under /web:

web.php should be under `config/` not under `web/`

There may be a problem.

**EDIT 2**

Put `.htaccess` file in root and Try `localhost/hello` instead `localhost/hello/web`

Comment: I am sorry. It was a mistake in my writing. The web.php file is where it should be. Under config/